# Cropping images in Itext

Tags: java, itext, crop

is there an easy way to crop an Image in Itext?

I have the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(imgUrl);

connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
iStream = connection.getInputStream();
img = new Jpeg(url);

// a method like 
// img.crop(x1, y1, x2, y2) would be nice.
```

Now I want to "delete" a strip of let's say 20 pixels left and 20 pixels right.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could investigate using the clipping path. You'll need to know the width and height of the JPEG. The code might look something like this:

```
PdfTemplate t = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(850, 600);
t.rectangle(x+20,y+20, width-40, height-40);
t.clip();
t.newPath();
t.addImage(img, width, 0, 0, height, x, y);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to crop an image using PdfTemplate.

```
public static Image cropImage(Image image, PdfWriter writer, float x, float y, float width, float height) throws DocumentException {
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate t = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
    float origWidth = image.getScaledWidth();
    float origHeight = image.getScaledHeight();
    t.addImage(image, origWidth, 0, 0, origHeight, -x, -y);
    return Image.getInstance(t);
}
```

Notice this doesn't require calling t.rectangle(), t.clip() or t.newPath().

Comment: Nice to know. But, is this correct? I mean, I want to strip not to scale.

Comment: This doesn't scale the image at all. The reason it calls image.getScaledWidth() and image.getScaledHeight() is so that it will work correctly on an image that has been scaled. If the image has not been scaled the image.getScaledWidth() will be the same as image.getWidth().

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa what do all the parameters for `t.addImage` do? in the docs they are just listed as a,b,c,d,e,f and are all part of the "trasnformation matrix"! I basically have a rectangular image that i want to crop the top and bottom off.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix, a,b,c,d,e,f are all just values in a matrix will be multiplied by [x, y].

Answer (score 4):

Nathan's solution almost worked for me. The only problem left was white margins because of PdfTemplate having the same size as image to crop.

My solution:

```
public Image cropImage(PdfWriter writer, Image image, float leftReduction, float rightReduction, float topReduction, float bottomReduction) throws DocumentException {
    float width = image.getScaledWidth();
    float height = image.getScaledHeight();
    PdfTemplate template = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(
            width - leftReduction - rightReduction,
            height - topReduction - bottomReduction);
    template.addImage(image,
            width, 0, 0,
            height, -leftReduction, -bottomReduction);
    return Image.getInstance(template);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem,
and here's what i did:

Concept: 
Get the image as Buffered Image
Make the BufferedImage and render as Image (iText)

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
document.open();

//Get the image as Buffere Image
BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("image url"));

//Crop: Sample, get Upper Half of the image
BufferedImage awtImageUpper = awtImage.getSubimage(0, 0, awtImage.getWidth(), awtImage.getHeight()/2);

//Make BufferedImage and render as Image (in iText)
ByteArrayOutputStream baosImage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(awtImageUpper, "png", baosImage);
Image iTextImage = Image.getInstance(baosImage.toByteArray());


//Display Image in pdf
document.add(new Paragraph("image Upper half"));
document.add((Element) iTextImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

//4x6 inch photo height=432 width =288

```
// scale
if (isMatchFrame) {
    /* width */
    proportion = image.getWidth() / width;
    image.scaleAbsolute((float) width, image.getHeight() / proportion);
} else {
    /* hight */
    proportion = image.getHeight() / height;
    image.scaleAbsolute(image.getWidth() / proportion, (float) height);
}
// crop
document.setMargins((height - image.getHeight()/proportion) / 2, 0, (width - image.getWidth()/proportion) / 2 , 0);
```

can crop center photo. enjoy it.