# how to cut the image by itext Image Instance?

Tags: java, itext

I want to cut image by Itext,code as follows:

```
//com.itextpdf.text.Image  imageAbPath  is image absolute path
Image img = Image.getInstance(imageAbPath);
//how to rotate it ?

//how to cut it ?

//how to set image mask for it?

//how to write it to  disk?

//or how to write it to pdf?
```

please help,thanks.

Comment: Did you saw this question? [Cropping images in Itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134421/cropping-images-in-itext)

Comment: What do you mean by cutting? Shall the image data be cut to only contain the desired area? Or shall merely the desired area of the image be visible in viewers but the whole image can be embedded in the PDF? The latter is easy and a duplicate of e.g. the question @Sergey mentioned. The former is not a task for iText but for image processing APIs as a pre-processing step of your iText PDF process.

Comment: The itext image class is not designed to allow actual image manipulations. It is merely a wrapper for anything image-like to embed into a pdf you create with itext, with the addition that it has some attributes which control how the image is embedded. So the answer is: **You don't.**

Comment: Have you checked the answer @Sergey gave you a link to? It should partially answer your questions. Furthermore, please don't only edit extra questions into your question body but also reply to comments. You can add comments to your own question...

Comment: yes，I  try to  PdfTemplate，code as follow：                              PdfTemplate tmp = contentByte.createTemplate(cutWidth, cutHeight);
    tmp.addImage(tImgCover, oldWidth, 0, 0, oldHeight, -topX, -topY);
    tImgCover = Image.getInstance(tmp);                                                                           but，tImgCover.setImageMask(maskImg);  has no effect！！！